# Excel file dialog box appearing multiple times

Tags: excel, vba

I am using `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)` to allow a user to select a file to import data from. However, after the user selects a file it pops open the file dialog box again asking them to choose a file. It will do this 2-3 times before it continues on.

Have I accidentally created a loop?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Set myFile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

With myFile
    .Title = "Choose File"

    .AllowMultiSelect = False

    If .Show <> -1 Then
       Exit Sub
       ElseIf .Show <> 0 Then
       FileSelected = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

'data location & range to copy

mydata = "='[FileSelected]'!$C$10:$C$21" '<< change as required

'link to worksheet
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("C10:C21") '<< change as required
.Formula = mydata
'convert formula to text
.Value = .Value

End With
End Sub
```

So I have tried each of your solutions, and I am still getting two open file dialog boxes, however there is a difference between the two that I didn't notice before. the first box has the appropriate "Choose File" title, however the second box has "Update Values: FilesSelected" for the title. I also have added the last few lines that I excluded before. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.Show` method displays the File Dialog similarly to `Userform.Show`.  So every time you call `.Show` the Dialog is displayed.

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Title = "Choose File"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        FileSelected = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If

End With
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make it shorter :

```
filepath = Application.GetOpenFilename("All files (*.*),*.*")
If filepath = False Then Exit Sub
MsgBox filepath
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're calling the Show method twice.  Hence the dialog box displays twice.  Try the following instead...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim strPathAndFile As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Title = "Choose File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
        strPathAndFile = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `If .Show <> -1` just doesn't look right at all. That condition will `Exit Sub` if `.Show` returns a `Variant/Boolean` (`False`), but also it it returns a `Variant/String` actual file name, leaving `strPathAndFile` (wow dat name) unassigned.

Comment: Actually, according to the help file, the Show method `"Displays a file dialog box and returns a Long indicating whether the user pressed the Action button (-1) or the Cancel button (0). "`.  So it would seem appropriate.  And, also, the file name is actually returned from the SelectionItems property.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Gah, sorry I got confused with other means to do the same thing. Regardless, seems to me that checking `.SelectedItems.Count = 0` would be much easier to read. Does what it says, says what it does.

Comment: Yeah, I would agree with you there.  Using the `.SelectedItems.Count = 0` is easier to read.